# How to integrate Google Protocol Buffer to an xCode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, serialization, marshalling, protocol-buffers

I'm currently trying to integrate this third-party Objective-C version of Google Protocol Buffer into my xCode project so I can compile it:
[Objective-C implementation of Google Protocol Buffer](http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers)

Now I've successfully made and installed the library and everything that has to do with setup. My problems lie in understanding some of the setup instructions. More specifically the step-by-step list found under **Project Integration** under the supplied link above.

> Add a reference to /Classes/ProtocolBuffers.h in your project and add the following line to your pch file: #import "ProtocolBuffers.h"

Now with this I suppose what is meant is to simply drag the header file into your project? Unfortunately when I do this, all I get is a linker error that says the file can't be found.

> Get Info on your build target

I'm just overall confused about what this is supposed to mean?

> Add ProtocolBuffers as a Direct Dependency of your build target.

Unfortunately I do not really have much experience with this kind of work in xCode. I tried to search around on google, and people suggested to simply drag the entire project into your main project, and then add it as a reference for your target, but I could never really get this to work. Anyone that can point me to some good articles on how to do this?

All in all I'm just trying to figure all this out and would be awesome if someone could clarify what is meant or point me to article or other forum posts that explain how to do it :)

Thank you all for the help :)

**[EDIT]**

It also appears that the library which the setup is referring to called libProtocolBuffers.a is missing?

Answer (score 3):

I hope you have successfully installed the library and created the .pb.h and .pb.m files for a test .proto file.

I'm using [an ARC enabled iOS 5 version](https://github.com/regwez/protobuf-objc-iOS5) of the metasyntactic project. But I think the steps are, more or less, the same.

- Add those .pb.h and pb.m files to your project (simple add files to project).
  When you build you'll see an error in the .pb.h file saying that  is missing. So add that file from *install path -> src -> runtime -> Classes*. and add *#import "ProtocolBuffers.h"* to your .pch file.
- Again building will give errors saying that some .h file could'nt be found.
  Click on the *project target -> Build Settings tab -> Search Path -> Header Search Path* : add the "src" folder's path and click on recursive checkbox

**Now to add the Target Dependency**

In Project Navigator Pane, *right click on the project -> Add files to project -> Navigate to install path -> src -> runtime :* add the ProtocolBuffers.xcodeproj file. You should be able to see the entire ProtocolBuffer project inside your own project.

Now go to *project target -> Build Phases tab -> Target Dependencies* : click on + and you'll be able to see ProtocolBuffer project targets. Click on ProtocolBuffers to add dependency.

Now in the same tab click on "Link Binary with Libraries", click on +. Add the libProtocolBuffers.a file and build.

The libProtocolBuffers.a is actually not missing, rather its the output of the ProtocolBuffers project you just added.